# How can I use Offline map in open layer v6

Tags: asp.net-core, openlayers, openlayers-6

I have a project in asp.net core and I want to use offline map, Does open layer v6 support offline map?
I can't find an example, any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to download the `ol.js` and `ol.css` or use the [link](https://openlayers.org/download/) from the document.
2. Then you need to use bigemap to download the map file(png).
3. Put them in wwwroot, then reference them in layout.

   ```
   <link href="./ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="./ol.js"></script>
   ```
4. Select a place to put the map, and adjust the size.

   ```
   <div id="map" class="map"></div>
   ```
5. Use js to draw this map.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map', //the id of map 
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),//Set the map center
      zoom: 4 //Default load level
     })
    });

     var offLineMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'tile/a.png' // the map has been downloaded
      })
     });
     map.addLayer(offLineMap);
   </script>
   ```

Comment: @MoHaMMaD, could you mark this answer, or do you have any other issues?